# css navigation sub menu not showing right

Tags: css, less

Hello i have the following live example http://jsfiddle.net/vfubN/4/ where you can see a navigation in action if you check out docs you will see that the submenu isn't working right. Can someone help me out fixing it ? Seems that i can't see the solution even if it's in front of my eyes.

**HTML**

```
<header role="banner">
    <div class="navbar fixed-top navbar-theme-aizio-background">
        <div class="inner-navbar"> <a href="#" class="brand pull-right">Test<sub>name</sub></a>
            <div class="container">
                <nav id="menu" class="nav" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="inactive-responsive" id="inactive-responsive">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" id="menutoggle" class="navtoggle" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true"  class="icon-home"></i></span>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="inactive-dropdown" id="dropdownToggle"> <a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-signal"></i></span>Docs</a>
                            <ul class="inactive-dropdown vertical-navigation" id="inactive-dropdown">
                                <li> <a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-code"></i></span>ssss</a>
                                </li>
                                <li> <a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-qrcode"></i></span>Portfolio</a>
                                </li>
                                <li> <a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-print"></i></span>Blog</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li> <a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-heart"></i></span>The  team</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-envelope"></span></i>google.ro</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-cog"></i></span>Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-cloud"></i></span>Blog</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-heart"></i></span>The  team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-envelope"></span></i>Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.navbar [class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.navbar {
  background: #4d4d4d;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.9em #555555;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.9em #555555;
}
.navbar-inner {
  width: 100%;
}
/*
Navbar Brand Styles
 */
.inner-navbar .brand {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
}
.inner-navbar .brand sub,
sup {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.inner-navbar .brand:hover {
  color: #004b67 /*#383838 */;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.inner-navbar nav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.inner-navbar nav button#responsiveToggle {
  display: none;
}
.inner-navbar nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner-navbar nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 130px;
  min-width: 8.1rem;
}
.inner-navbar nav li:first-child a,
li:last-child a {
  border-left: 0;
}
.inner-navbar nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.inner-navbar nav a:hover {
  color: #004b67;
}
.inactive-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
.active-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1f2024;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.active-dropdown li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* nice blue color background-color: #2aa4cf; */
}
.active-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.vertical-navigation {
  float: none;
}
.vertical-navigation i {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
/*
Themes
 */
.navbar-theme-blue-marina {
  background: #2aa4cf;
}
.navbar-theme-aizio-background,
.active-dropdown li {
  background: #004b67;
}
.navbar-theme-aizio-background a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-theme-aizio-background ul li a:hover {
  color: #b2e558;
}
.navbar-theme-aizio-background .brand:hover {
  color: #b2e558;
}
/*  ------------------------------  RESPONSIVE STYLES ----------------------------------------------------*/
/*Styles for screen 768px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .active-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .active-dropdown li a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 0 solid #666;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li a {
    border-left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #383838;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li a:hover {
    background: #636363;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav a {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .inner-navbar nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 0 solid #666;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0a0d;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav button#responsiveToggle {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav button#responsiveToggle {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav button#responsiveToggle:before {
    content: '';
    /* 1 */
    display: block;
    /* 2 */
  }
  .inner-navbar nav button#responsiveToggle:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* When JavaScript is enabled, we hide the menu */
  .js .inner-navbar nav .inactive-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Displaying the menu when the user has clicked on the button */
  .active-responsive a:hover {
    font-size: 2em;
    opacity: .5;
  }
  .active-responsive a:hover i {
    display: none;
  }
  .fixed-top {
    position: relative;
  }
}
/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .active-dropdown li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .inner-navbar nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0a0d;
  }
}
/* RETINA */
/*  ------------------------------  RESPONSIVE STYLES ----------------------------------------------------*/
/*Styles for screen 768px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .inner-navbar .brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .inner-navbar .brand {
    display: block;
  }
  .inner-navbar .pull-left {
    float: none;
  }
  .inner-navbar .pull-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
/* RETINA */
```

Comment: What you need? you have mediaqueries on what size isn't working? is the alignment of the icons and text or the background?

Comment: the font icon and text aren't aligned right

Comment: you want this like the horizontal or side by side?

Comment: the sub menu i want it vertically to be aligned ( it already is ). if you check out the jsfiddle you will see that the text from the sub menu including the icon are messed up pretty bad. the text doesn't align vertically correct, the icons seem to be at the right position maybe i should add to them some padding no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems because styles for the horizontal menu are affecting the vertical one, i made this changes in your CSS:

```
.inner-navbar nav .vertical-navigation li a{
  text-align:left;
 }
.vertical-navigation i {
  float:none;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.vertical-navigation li [class^="icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/vfubN/13/**

Comment: when i get home i'll ready the code a little bit more and see the changes.. you have made... having a bad week and it's not over yet
So far it seems that i forgot to point the classes correctly and made a few ones "global"

Answer (score 2):

I have the same menu and it works. I give you the CSS. You still have more for you to rename.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Index</title>
<style type="text/css">
#menu, #menu ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #999;
}
#menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    left:auto;
}
#menu a {
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
    <li id='accueil'><a href="index.php">accueil</a></li><!--
     --><li><a href="" class='catalogue'>CATALOGUE</a></li><!--
     --><li><a class='fonction' href="">FONCTIONNEMENT</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href='toto'>toto</a></li><!--
         --><li><a href='toto'>tutu</a></li><!--
         --><li><a href='toto'>titi</a></li><!--
         --><li><a href='toto'>tata</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!--
     --><li><a class='service' href="">LES SERVICES</a></li><!--
     --><li><a class='commande' href="">COMMANDE</a></li><!--
     --><li><a class='contact' href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```